# inheritance base class implements interface INotifyPropertyChanged can child class make use of it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a datagrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection. I would like to know when a property is changed. I have a similar datagrid in the same application where I have this working. However this datagrid is bound to a class that inherits from another class.

So a simple code snippet shown below.

In the child do I have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface although that seems bit of a pain to me and not really making use of inheritance. Can I simply just make the OnPropertyChanged public or is that wrong?

**Base Class**

```
class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public int Age
     { 
         get 
         { return _age;}
         set 
         { 
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
         }
     }

     int _age

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

}
```

**Child Class**

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public bool Fleas
     { 
         get 
         { return _fleas;}
         set 
         { 
            _fleas = value;
         }
     }

     int _fleas

}
```

Comment: There's no inheritance shown in your code... what have you not included?

Comment: sorry dog is supposed to inherit from animal - updated my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`protected` would probably be what you want, but generally, yes.

One thing you often find, for example in MVVM frameworks such as Caliburn.Micro, is having an abstract class like `PropertyChangedBase` that has  nothing but that simple implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that all classes that want to make use of this ultimately have to inherit from `PropertyChangedBase`, which may not always be desired or possible.